# Maintaining Go Pointers to Shared Memory

Tags: go, garbage-collection, ipc, cgo

From what research I have done there are no libraries out there to create and manage shared memory in Go. I thought it might be easy enough to pull of with some basic cgo code, and as it turns out it is. The concern that I would like to address before I move forward involves the interaction between the Go runtime and Go pointers to shared memory.

To demonstrate my concern, I created a simple Go struct

```
type Test struct {
    X int32
    Y float64
    Z [5]int32
}
```

That I expose in two seperate Go programs, A and B along with some cgo code.

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int get_mem() {
    key_t key = ftok("shared_mem",65);
    return shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);
}

char * attach_mem(int id) {
    return (char*) shmat(id,(void*)0,0);
}

void detach_mem(char * str) {
    shmdt(str);
}

void destroy_mem(int id) {
    shmctl(id,IPC_RMID,NULL);
}

void write(char * str, char * data, int len) {
    memcpy(str, data, len);
}
```

Program A then creates a `Test` struct, writes it to shared memory, creates a `*Test` pointer called `ptr` to that memory, waits 10 seconds, then prints the value at `ptr`.

```
// Program A
func main() {
    id := C.get_mem()
    str := C.attach_mem(id)
    dataLocal := Test{1, 2.0, [5]int32{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}
    C.write(str, (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&dataLocal)), C.int(unsafe.Sizeof(dataLocal)))
    ptr := (*Test)(unsafe.Pointer(str))
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(ptr)
    C.detach_mem(str)
    C.destroy_mem(id)
}
```

In those 10 seconds, Program B starts, creates a `*Test` pointer to the shared memory, and modifies one of the fields.

```
// Program B
func main() {
    id := C.get_mem()
    str := C.attach_mem(id)
    data := (*Test)(unsafe.Pointer(str))
    data.X = 10
    C.detach_mem(str)
}
```

Obviously this is not a practical IPC implementation, but it works. Program A prints

```
&{10 2 [3 4 5 6 7]}
```

My concern is that the Go runtime, namely the garbage collector, won't play nice with this implementation. Specifically, how will Go treat `ptr` in Program A? I know that the Go GC will move data in the heap around, but does that apply to data referenced by Go pointers that lie outside of the heap? Now that a Go pointer references this data, will it be garbage collected?

If neither of those issues apply, is this approach unsafe or otherwise considered to be bad style? If so what other alternatives are there?

Comment: Just a quick Google yields this link: https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating.  Apparently, communicating via shared memory using a POSIX-style shared memory interface is something the Go designers thought was in poor form.  I'm not saying what you're doing is a bad idea if you know what you are doing.  However, it's easy to get wrong.

Comment: RE the garbage collector, several things.  First, it _only_ works on heap objects, stuff on the stack does get GC'd because it vanishes when the stack frame does.  Second, the compiler chooses whether to put it on the heap or stack via escape analysis (not sure how this works with cgo pointers, though).  Third, the garbage collector won't do anything to memory as long as there's still a reference to it in the code.  Also, pretty sure it only works on _Go_ types, so arbitrary cgo pointers are out of bounds.  It won't GC your struct in program B, as far as I know.

Comment: Also, as @RunFun points out, sharing memory is a no-no.  Go specifically makes it difficult, and also strongly discourages it, because it's where a HUGE amount of race conditions come from.  Far better to communicate between concurrent processes (or even concurrent programs) rather than share memory.

Comment: Although RunFun and Kaedys are right from the philosophical perspective, I still find this question interesting from a technical point of view. The answer might be hidden here somewhere https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/yNis7bQG_rY/yaJFoSx1hgIJ

Comment: First, read the documentaion: [Passing pointers](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers), [Command cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/). Now that you have read the documentation, what, specifically, don't you understand? The `ptr` value is not a Go pointer.